# Xcode - Is this MVC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm a part-time notepad website coder taking steps into IOS apps. I got my first mac last week and have cobbled together a half working app. Now, convinced by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443020/781200), I am restarting trying to learn MVC. I am on a very steep learning curve so please bear with me.

I have read up on MVC, separation of layers, three boxes and some arrows, I get it. However, translating the theory into the real world is frustrating. Most example apps I have looked at do not seem to use MVC. Even this [LazyTableImages example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple seems to use `app delegate` as the model which confuses me. I have built on this excellently [simple MVC example](http://fromideatoapp.com/downloads/example/).

My app retrieves location markers from a web service. I have a tabbed application using ARC. One tab has a Mapkit map to display the markers.

A simple class to hold a marker record:

```
@interface MarkerRecord : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDecimalNumber *lat;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDecimalNumber *lon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *des;
```

A Model class, holding a collection of Marker classes, to serve both views. This is my Model class .h:

```
@interface MarkersModel : NSObject

- (void)getMarkers; // Send HTTP GET to web service to retrieve JSON markers
- (void)postMarker; // Send HTTP POST to web service to INSERT new marker record
```

And the implementation:

```
@interface MarkersModel ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *data;
@end

@implementation MarkersModel
@synthesize data;

- (void)getMarkers
{
    // Send HTTP GET to web service to retrieve JSON markers
    ...
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    // Thanks to Restkit data is an array of Marker classes
    data = objects;

    // Pass data to controller

}
```

A mapViewController class .h:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "MarkersModel.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
    MarkersModel *markersModel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@interface MapViewController ()
@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create instance of markers model
    markersModel = [[MarkersModel alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [markersModel getMarkers];
}

- (void)putMarkersOnMap
{
    // To be called by Markers Model 
    ...
}
```

Here's my main question:

- Is my code outline above (the beginnings of) a decent MVC implementation?

If so:

- how do I get the Model to update the Controller ( i.e. how do I get MarkersModel.objectLoader function to call mapViewController.putMarkersOnMap)?

I strongly suspect the answer is a custom delegate on the controller but I cannot for the life of me see how to implement it. I cannot relate any examples to my situation. I think I need something like this on the controller:

```
@class MapViewController;
@protocol MapViewControllerDelegate;
```

While I am at it some additional questions:

- Will I create any dangling pointers - I suspect something should be `unsafe_unretained` (I am compiling to 4.3)?
- Is my MarkersModel declaration in the controller class correct? I am concerned that it will not be managed by ARC. I also suspect it is public but should be private.
- Should the MarkersModel.getMarkers method be static?

I hope this is clear and an acceptable question. Thanks for your patience, Polly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is my code outline above (the beginnings of) a decent MVC implementation?

By my standards, yes

> how do I get the Model to update the Controller

You are correct, you want to use a delegate.  You declare the delegate protocol along with the class it is a delegate for.  So expanding on your `MarkersModel` header:

```
@protocol MarkersModelDelegate<NSObject>
-(void) markersDidUpdate:(MarkersModel*)model;
@end

@interface MarkersModel : NSObject
{
    __weak id<MarkersModelDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(weak,nonatomic) id<MarkersModelDelegate> delegate;
```

Then in your view controller:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate, MarkersModelDelegate> {
```

Then in the model implementation:

```
@implementation MarkersModel

@synthesize delegate;

//...

-(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    // Thanks to Restkit data is an array of Marker classes
    data = objects;

    // Pass data to controller
    if( delegate != nil )
    {
        [delegate markersDidUpdate:self];
    }
}
```

> Will I create any dangling pointers - I suspect something should be unsafe_unretained (I am compiling to 4.3)?

Not that I am aware of

> Is my MarkersModel declaration in the controller class correct? I am concerned that it will not be managed by ARC. I also suspect it is public but should be private.

You can declare it as private by adding the `@private` header beforehand:

```
@interface MapViewController...
{
@private
MarkersModel *markersModel;
...
```

> Should the MarkersModel.getMarkers method be static?

If by static, you mean as a class-level instead of instance-level method, that entirely depends on your implementation.  If all `MarkersModel` objects are supposed to retain the same data, then yes it makes sense to make it class-level.  But if each `MarkersModel` object is supposed to retain its own set of `Markers` then no, it should remain an instance-level method

Comment: This is good; use of delegates is very common.  One alternative you might want to also evaluate is "Key-Value Observing" if you have any potential for more than one controller being interested in changes to the model. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: @PhillipMills Helpful link, I've actually just recently gotten really down into the nitty-gritty of how to improve my MVC programming, this should really help me out

Comment: Just for completion in case this helps someone in the future - @DanF answer worked great with the addition of one line in the MapViewControllor.viewDidLoad function. After creating the markersModel instance I added: `[markersModel setDelegate:self];`

Comment: @Polly Yes, that is necessary, I'm sorry I forgot that little bit.  You can also do `markersModel.delegate = self;` the two lines are 100% equivalent